# Call php functions in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, function

Somethimes we need use some php function in javascript right?

What you think about this ajax solution for this:

In js code, we write function `php_function(func_name, arguments)`

argument `func_name` is php function name

argument `arguments` is php function arguments

for example we need use php's function `base64_encode()` in javascript.

This is js code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {


    function php_function(func_name, arguments) {

        var result;
        $.ajax({

            url: //url to php file,
            type: "POST",
            async: false, 
            data: {f_name: func_name, args: arguments},
            success: function ( htm ) {

                result = JSON.parse(htm)

            }

        });

        return result;

    }


    var arguments = ["OTO"];

    alert( php_function("base64_encode", arguments) ); // T1RP



});
```

and this is php:

```
echo json_encode( call_user_func_array( $_POST['f_name'], $_POST['args'] ) );
```

May be this method will usefull...

Comment: Is this a question? Anyway, you should take a look at [PHPJS](http://phpjs.org).

Comment: So dangerous for your security, all users can call some php malicious code

Comment: @Kolink No, this no question. this is may be solution... I know about `PHPJS`, but here every function has own not small code. In this solution, we need change only function names and arguments and we got result.

Comment: pass a callback for get result instead of directly use the return, also filter allowed function in the php

Answer (score 1):

The question statement is a bit bad, it would be better to perhaps ask : is there anything wrong with this approach?

The answer to that is: yes, this is terrible. You just poked a huge security hole in your system.